# jQuery Executing Too Early in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, selenium

I have a jQuery menu which expands upon mouseover.  All sub-menu items can be clicked on and some sub-menu items have further sub-items when hovered over.

I want to temporarily disable the click event of one of the mid-level menu items so that clicking on it will not fire its click event but will open the next sub-level (I have tried simulating hover over with the Selenium Actions class but it doesn't work).

I have the following code:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("$('a:contains(Parent Menu Item)').click();");

((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("$('a:contains(Child Menu Item)').off('click');");
```

The first line works: the menu expands and the child element is visible.  The second line has no effect.

How can I get the jQuery to run in the order it appears in my code?

Comment: Can you get it working in developer console?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: If you remove the click handler then how would it open the child menu?

Comment: Have you tried waiting till element you try to click disable whatever becomes visible? I have used WebdriverIO not directly selenium driver but I know it can be done. Something like this maybe? WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ID"))); Notice wait.until :)

Comment: @TarunLalwani The <a> tag click handler doesn't open the child menu.  That's handled by the menu itself.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith I'm able to find the element by TagName using Selenium.  The second line above, which turns off the click event, comes after that in the code.  The issue is the jQuery firing too early, not where it appears in the code.

Comment: What makes you feel the jQuery is firing too early? Because you only control when the jQuery is being executed through your code?

Comment: You said, you need to mousehover to expand the parent menu then why are you clicking in first line of code?

Comment: @TarunLalwani The fact that it can find the parent element, which is always visible, but can't find the child element, which only become visible when the parent is clicked/hovered over makes me think the jQuery is firing before the element appears, regardless of where I've put the IJavaScriptExecutor.

Comment: @Kapil The top level menu elements don't have a click event.  That's why I'm clicking in the first line of the code.  If I could simulate a hover over, I wouldn't need to click anything, but the MoveToElement method of the Actions class doesn't seem to simulate a hover over, and I haven't found any other way to do it.